A simplified Blackjack C++ OOP console game
This is my first time writing something bigger with OOP. A simplified version of the card game BlackJack. Hand splitting currently isn't implemented.
File tree
build
header
└── class
    ├── deck.h
    ├── account.h
    └── hand.h
└── blackjack.h
source
├── func.cpp
└── main.cpp

main.cpp
#include "../header/blackjack.h"

bool playBlackjack(Account &playerAccount);

int main() {
    SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);

    Account playerAccount;
    char menuChoice = '1';
    int winStreak = 0;

    // Display menu and start the game
    while (menuChoice) {
        menuChoice = playerAccount.DisplayMenu();
        switch (menuChoice) {
            case '0':
                return 0;
            case '1':
                if (!playerAccount.checkBalance()) playerAccount.registerUser();
                srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(nullptr)));
                std::cout << "Win streak: " << winStreak;
                playBlackjack(playerAccount) ? winStreak++ : winStreak = 0; 
                system("pause");
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "Please choose between 0 and 1" << std::endl;
                Sleep(1000);
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


bool playBlackjack(Account &playerAccount) {
    PlayerHand playerHand(playerAccount);
    Hand dealerHand;
    Deck cardDeck;

    bool gameEnded = false;
    char playChoice;

    std::cout << std::endl << "Please place your bets: ";
    playerAccount.placeBet();

    // Draw two cards for both player and dealer
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        playerHand.drawCard(cardDeck);
        dealerHand.drawCard(cardDeck);
    }

    while (!gameEnded) {
        system("cls");

        // Determine who won, after the player chose to stand
        if (playerHand.getChoseToStand()) {
            while (dealerHand.sum() < 17) {
                dealerHand.drawCard(cardDeck);
            }

            if (dealerHand.sum() > 21) {
                playerHand.setHasWon(true);
            } else if (dealerHand.sum() > playerHand.sum()) {
                dealerHand.setHasWon(true);
            } else if (playerHand.sum() > dealerHand.sum()) {
                playerHand.setHasWon(true);
            } else {
                dealerHand.setHasWon(false);
                playerHand.setHasWon(false);
            }
            gameEnded = true;
        }

        // Determine who won, if the game is cut short
        if (!gameEnded) {
            if (dealerHand.checkForBj()) {
                dealerHand.setHasWon(true);
                gameEnded = true;
            } else if (playerHand.checkForBj()) {
                dealerHand.setHasWon(false);
                gameEnded = true;
            } else if (playerHand.sum() > 21) {
                dealerHand.setHasWon(true);
                gameEnded = true;
            }
        }
        
        // Display bet and hands
        std::cout << playerAccount.getName() << "'s bet: " << playerAccount.getBet() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Dealer's hand: ";
        if (!gameEnded) {
            dealerHand.display(1);
            std::cout << "covered";
        } else dealerHand.display();
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Your hand: "; playerHand.display(); std::cout << std::endl;

        // Display summary after the game ends
        if (gameEnded) {
            if (playerHand.getHasWon()) {
                std::cout << playerAccount.getName() << " wins!" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "+ " << 2 * playerAccount.getBet() << std::endl;
                playerAccount.setToken(playerAccount.getToken() + 2 * playerAccount.getBet());
            } else if (dealerHand.getHasWon()) {
                std::cout << "Dealer wins!" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "- " << playerAccount.getBet() << std::endl;
                playerAccount.setToken(playerAccount.getToken() - playerAccount.getBet());
            } else {
                std::cout << "Tie with dealer" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "+ " << playerAccount.getBet() << std::endl;
                playerAccount.setToken(playerAccount.getToken() + playerAccount.getBet());
            }

            playerAccount.saveBalance();
            return playerHand.getHasWon();
        }

        // Get player's choice
        std::cout << std::endl << "Choice: [1] Stand [2] Hit";
        if (playerHand.canDoubleDown()) std::cout << " [3] Double down";
        std::cout << std::endl;

        playChoice = char(getch());
        switch (playChoice) {
            case '1':
                playerHand.stand();
                break;
            case '2':
                playerHand.hit(cardDeck);
                break;
            case '3':
                if (playerHand.canDoubleDown()) playerHand.doubleDown();
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "Invalid choice. Please choose again.";
                Sleep(300);
                break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

func.cpp
#include "../header/blackjack.h"

// Account class

void Account::registerUser() {
    std::cout << "Enter name: ";
    std::cin >> name;
    tokenAmount = 1000;
    saveFile.open(fileName, std::ios::out);
    saveFile << name << std::endl << tokenAmount;
    saveFile.close();
}

void Account::saveBalance() {
    saveFile.open(fileName, std::ios::out);
    saveFile << name << std::endl << tokenAmount;
    saveFile.close();
}

bool Account::checkBalance() {
    return tokenAmount > 0;
}

void Account::placeBet() {
    while (!(std::cin >> betAmount) || betAmount <= 0 || betAmount > tokenAmount) {
        std::cout << "Invalid input. Try again: ";
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    tokenAmount -= betAmount;
    saveBalance();
}

char Account::DisplayMenu() {
    system("cls");
    std::cout << "User: " << name << std::endl
        << "Balance: " << tokenAmount << std::endl << std::endl
        << "Blackjack? " << std::endl 
        << "[0] Exit" << std::endl
        << "[1] Play" << std::endl << std::endl;
    return char(getch());
}

Account::Account() {
        std::string textLine;
        int lineIndicator = 1;

        saveFile.open(fileName, std::ios::in);
        if (saveFile.is_open()) {
            while (getline(saveFile, textLine)) {
                switch (lineIndicator) {
                    case 1:
                        name = textLine;
                        if (name.empty()) {
                            std::cout << "Couldn't resolve username, register again" << std::endl;
                            saveFile.close();
                            registerUser();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        tokenAmount = std::atoi(textLine.c_str());
                        if (tokenAmount <= 0) {
                            std::cout << "Savings are either 0 or corrupted, register again" << std::endl;
                            saveFile.close();
                            registerUser();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    lineIndicator++;
                }
                saveFile.close();
        } else {
            registerUser();
        }
    }

// Hand class

void Hand::display(int cardNumber) {
    if (cardNumber == 0) {
        for (auto card : cards) {
            std::cout << card.first << card.second << "  ";
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < cardNumber; i++) {
            std::cout << cards[i].first << cards[i].second << "  ";
        }
    }
}

void Hand::drawCard(Deck &deck) {
    cards.push_back(deck.drawCard());
}

int Hand::sum() {
    int sum = 0;
    int aceCount = 0;
    for (auto card : cards) {
        sum += cardValues.at(card.first);
        if (card.first == "A") {
            aceCount++;
        }
    }
    while (sum > 21 && aceCount > 0) {
        sum -= 10;
        aceCount--;
    }
    return sum;
}

bool Hand::checkForBj() {
    return cards.size() == 2 && sum() == 21;
}

void Hand::stand() {
    choseToStand = true;
}

void Hand::hit(Deck &deck) {
    drawCard(deck);
}

Hand::Hand() : choseToStand(false), hasWon(false) {}

// Hand (child) PlayerHand

bool PlayerHand::canDoubleDown() {
    return !doubledDown && (playerAccount.getBet() <= playerAccount.getToken()) && cards.size() == 2;
}

void PlayerHand::doubleDown() {
    playerAccount.setBet(playerAccount.getBet() * 2);
    doubledDown = true;
}

PlayerHand::PlayerHand(Account &acc) : playerAccount(acc), doubledDown(false) {};

// Deck Class

Deck::Deck() {
    for (auto suit : suits) {
        for (auto rank : ranks) {
            cards.emplace_back(rank, suit);
        }
    }

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());
    std::shuffle(cards.begin(), cards.end(), g);
}

std::pair<std::string, std::string> Deck::drawCard() {
    auto card = cards.back();
    cards.pop_back();
    return card;
}

blackjack.h
#ifndef BLACKJACK_H
#define BLACKJACK_H

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <limits>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <random>

#include "class/account.h"
#include "class/deck.h"
#include "class/hand.h"

class Account;
class Deck;
class Hand;
class PlayerHand;

const char fileName[17] = "Credentials.save";
const std::array<std::string, 4> suits = {"♥", "♦", "♣", "♠"};
const std::array<std::string, 13> ranks = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
const std::map<std::string, short> cardValues = {
    {"2", 2}, {"3", 3}, {"4", 4}, {"5", 5}, {"6", 6},
    {"7", 7}, {"8", 8}, {"9", 9}, {"10", 10}, {"J", 10},
    {"Q", 10}, {"K", 10}, {"A", 11}
};

#endif 

account.h
#ifndef ACCOUNT_H
#define ACCOUNT_H

#include "../blackjack.h"

class Account {
private:
    std::fstream saveFile;
    std::string name;
    int tokenAmount, betAmount;
public:
    void registerUser();
    void saveBalance();
    bool checkBalance();
    void placeBet();
    char DisplayMenu();

    std::string getName() const { return name; }
    int getToken() const { return tokenAmount; }
    int getBet() const { return betAmount; }
    
    void setToken(int token) { tokenAmount = token; } 
    void setBet(int bet) { betAmount = bet; }

    Account();
};

#endif

hand.h
#ifndef HAND_H
#define HAND_H

#include "../blackjack.h"

class Hand {
protected:
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> cards;
    bool choseToStand;
    bool hasWon;
public:
    void display(int cardNumber = 0);
    void drawCard(Deck &deck);
    int sum();
    bool checkForBj();

    void stand();
    void hit(Deck &deck);

    bool getHasWon() const { return hasWon; }
    bool getChoseToStand() const { return choseToStand; }

    void setHasWon(bool win) { hasWon = win; }

    Hand();
};

class PlayerHand : public Hand {
private:
    Account &playerAccount;
    bool doubledDown;
public:
    bool canDoubleDown();
    void doubleDown();

    PlayerHand(Account &acc);
};

#endif

deck.h
#ifndef DECK_H
#define DECK_H

#include "../blackjack.h"

class Deck {
private:
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> cards;
public:
    std::pair<std::string, std::string> drawCard();

    Deck();
};

#endif


Miscellaneous observations
I already have a long answer examining blackjack.h; these are the unrelated issues I've spotted, in no particular order.


            Sleep(1000);


This seems to be a platform-specific equivalent of a standard C++ function:
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

             using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
             std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);

Prefer to use standard C++ where you can, and cross-platform libraries where you can't - that will reduce or eliminate porting work later when you want to support different target platforms.

The C library rand() function is notoriously poor, without any guarantees as the the quality of its randomness.  If we want to prevent cheating, we should be using the much better facilities specified in <random>.

We seem to have a fondness for flushing output streams using std::endl where '\n' would be perfectly fine.

When we write the file, we open it as a text file, which means that each line needs to be terminated with \n - yet that's missing from the final line here:

void Account::saveBalance() {
    saveFile.open(fileName, std::ios::out);
    saveFile << name << std::endl << tokenAmount;
    saveFile.close();
}


Also, we never inspect the stream after close() to see whether our write was successful.  If our file wasn't fully written, we'll want to take some recovery action.
It's not clear why saveFile is a member of the Account object, as it is only ever open within the scope of a single function.  It would be better to use separate local std::ofstream or std::ifstream objects in each function.


    system("cls");


If this was meant to be std::system(), then this is another source of platform-dependency.


   if (saveFile.is_open()) {
        while (getline(saveFile, textLine)) {
            switch (lineIndicator) {
                case 1:
                    ⋮
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ⋮
                    break;
                }
                lineIndicator++;
            }
            saveFile.close();


A loop seems to be the wrong structure here - we're performing two operations sequentially, so it's better to express that as sequential code.

    } else {
        registerUser();


Here, we know that saveFile isn't open - but we don't know why.  Perhaps the file isn't readable by this user?  Or we've exhausted our limit of open files (unlikely, but possible)?  Those error cases probably warrant very different action than the case where the file didn't exist.


void Hand::display(int cardNumber) {
    if (cardNumber == 0) {
        for (auto card : cards) {
            std::cout << card.first << card.second << "  ";
        }
    } else {
        ⋮
    }
}


This function is strongly tied to std::cout - there's no way to send this output to any other stream.


        case '3':
            if (playerHand.canDoubleDown()) playerHand.doubleDown();
            break;


If this option wasn't presented to the user, then shouldn't it be an error to select it, rather than being quietly ignored?  In this case, because it immediately precedes the default case, we can simply
            case '3':
                if (playerHand.canDoubleDown()) {
                    playerHand.doubleDown();
                    break;
                }
                [[fallthrough]];
            default:



std::cout << "Enter name: ";
std::cin >> name;


Many (most?) people's names contain spaces, so it's probably a good idea to read a full line here rather than just a single word.

General Observations
There are a few good practices here, the include guards are implemented properly. Overall the code should be reworked following best practices and then a follow up question with a link back to this question should be posted.
Class Files in C++ - Implementing Objects
The accepted practice in C++ is that a class is implemented by 2 files, class.h and class.cpp. This program is currently not following accepted practices. The file structure for this program should look something like:
build
header
└── class
    ├── deck.h
    ├── account.h
    ├── playerhand.h
    └── hand.h
└── blackjack.h
source
├── deck.cpp
├── account.cpp
├── hand.cpp
├── playerhand.cpp
└── main.cpp

One of the reasons for Object Oriented programming is to have reusable objects that can be used in other programs. This can only be done when there is a .cpp file to match the .h file.
The program as it is currently implemented is not really object oriented, because there is only one .cpp file.
Including Header Files
The mechanism to implement including header files in both C and C++ is to copy the header file into the file where it is included.
The best practice for this is to only include header files where they are necessary, and generally only include them in .cpp files.
We only include header files within header files if the file would not compile without it.
An example in the current code is that account.h should include string and fstream.
#ifndef ACCOUNT_H
#define ACCOUNT_H

#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class Account {
private:
    std::fstream saveFile;
    std::string name;
    int tokenAmount, betAmount;
public:
    void registerUser();
    void saveBalance();
    bool checkBalance();
    void placeBet();
    char DisplayMenu();

    std::string getName() const { return name; }
    int getToken() const { return tokenAmount; }
    int getBet() const { return betAmount; }
    
    void setToken(int token) { tokenAmount = token; } 
    void setBet(int bet) { betAmount = bet; }

    Account();
};

#endif


Splitting Hands
The problem you had with splitting hands is a design issue, not a coding issue. It indicates that the classes are not well designed. A simple way to implement this would be to allow a player to have 2 or more hands, each hand is played separately.

So you are good at C/C++, that's why you understood the post better than us :) That's a good thing :)

@BillalBegueradj Good I'm not sure, I do know my way around in them. There are people on this site that are much better than me in C and C++, at least 5 that I can think of offhand. There were things that had to be addressed in the code.

Actually, there are two files ending .cpp, namely func.cpp and main.cpp.  Doesn't affect the validity of your observation - the class member definitions are still all bundled into just one of those implementation files.

There are some problems with blackjack.h that I'd like to address.
What jumps out immediately is the large number of header files it includes.  Particularly problematic are two that are not part of standard C++, <windows.h> and <conio.h>.  These aren't provided by any package I have installed on my Linux workstation, so that means I can't build any of the objects that include this header - which is every single one of them.
For the declarations of blackjack.h, we only need to include
#include <array>
#include <map>
#include <string>

(Ironically, <string> is missing from the huge list at present)
I think it's likely that this large list is intended to be a convenience for its users, but that has a tendency to backfire in several ways - increasing compilation times for a start; also increasing coupling between modules and making it harder to re-use any part of it elsewhere.
It's particularly problematic that it includes all the project's headers - each of which cyclically include blackjack.h.  This means that any translation unit that includes any of them actually includes all of them.  It's what's known in software engineering as a god header.  When I generate the dependencies (e.g. using GCC's -M family of options), then that will show that every object file depends on every header.  So changing any one of the headers will cause everything to be recompiled.  That can be a real nuisance in larger projects.
There's also a problem with writing definitions in header files.  Remember that headers are textually included by the preprocessor into each translation unit.  That means that when we define (rather than simply declare) objects or functions in headers, we're creating object code to be emitted into each object file, rather than having a single instance in the program.
The correct way to use a header file is to write just the declarations:
#ifndef BLACKJACK_H
#define BLACKJACK_H

#include <map>
#include <array>
#include <string>

const char *const fileName = "Credentials.save";
const std::array<std::string, 4> suits;
const std::array<std::string, 13> ranks;
const std::map<std::string, short> cardValues;

#endif

And then put the definitions in a source file that's compiled just once:
#include "blackjack.h"          // to ensure that our definitions are
                                // consistent with the declarations

const char *const fileName = "Credentials.save";
const std::array<std::string, 4> suits = {"♥", "♦", "♣", "♠"};
const std::array<std::string, 13> ranks = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
const std::map<std::string, short> cardValues = {
    {"2", 2}, {"3", 3}, {"4", 4}, {"5", 5}, {"6", 6},
    {"7", 7}, {"8", 8}, {"9", 9}, {"10", 10}, {"J", 10},
    {"Q", 10}, {"K", 10}, {"A", 11}
};

I would argue that fileName isn't really anything to do with Blackjack itself, and doesn't need to be shared amongst all the sources - it's only relevant to the load and save functions, so its scope can be reduced to just the source file that implements those.

i added the fileName variable, just in case i wanted to change the save file name. Do you recommend creating a separate options file?

I think it could be local in the func.cpp translation unit where the save and load functions are.  None of the rest of the code needs to see it.

getch returns 0 (not '0'!) only in special circumstances. But normally it's supposed to always return an actual char.
Therefore I'm not a fan of you not only returning magic value 0 as-is to the caller of DisplayMenu, but also using that magical 0 as an escape condition of the main loop!
Some people will tell you that it's good enough if you adopt the low-level spirit of C. But since you're programming a game with an embryo of UI you should avoid two things : 1) don't mix return types (like I said 0 works, technically, but passing 0 as a char, especially when the char is supposed to have a meaning, is a bit like cheating the system), and 2) don't mix the meaning of function results ("exit the program because a system event happened" is a special meaning which is not in the same realm as "user pressed key something")
